# CustomPageFilter Error

Tags: aem

My requirement is to create a sitemap something similar provided in acs-aem-commons, I can get an xml by hitting  http://localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en.sitemap.xml , but it include the page on the basis of IsHideNav() or IsValid() criteria. Now there can be multiple properties in page-properties dialog like hide in navigation ,   on the basis of which my page will be include/exclude in sitemap. Below is the snippet from the SiteMapServlet :

```
for (Iterator<Page> children = page.listChildren(new PageFilter(), true); children.hasNext();) {
                write(children.next(), stream, resourceResolver);
            }
```

So what i think to implement CustomPageFilter rather than PageFilter which can use some extra parameters also. When i create CustomPageFilter, I am getting an error(Modifier 'volatile' not allowed here) for the below code :

```
  public volatile boolean includes(Object x0)
    {
        return includes((Page)x0);
    }
```

Any clue why this error is coming here and can we create a custom filter to achieve such functionality.

Thanks

Comment: `volatile` is allowed only on the fields, not on the methods.

Comment: Thanks, But i can see the same code when i decompile com.day.cq.wcm.api.PageFilter class.